# Erro em conexão cliente-servidor via socket

Tags: c++, socket, cliente-servidor

Sou iniciante em c++ e estou com dificuldades de fazer o meu código de cliente estabelecer uma conexão com o meu servidor em Python, o servidor está funcionando, porém o cliente sempre entrar no erro 4 e não completa a conexão, o que devo fazer?

```
#include<winsock.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

SOCKET s; 
int contador = TRUE;

int main()
{
    while ( contador )
    {
        int minhaPorta = 5000;
        char meuHost = '127.0.0.1';
        WSADATA wsadata;
        int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

        if (error)
        {
            std::cout<< "erro 1";
            contador=FALSE;
        }

        if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
        {
            WSACleanup();
            std::cout<<"erro 2";
            contador=FALSE;
        }

        SOCKADDR_IN target;
        target.sin_family = AF_INET;
        target.sin_port = htons (minhaPorta);
        target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (&meuHost);
        s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout<<"erro 3";
            contador=FALSE;
        }

        //Try connecting...
        if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout<<"erro 4";
            contador=FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"acerto 1";
            contador=TRUE;
        }
    }
}
void CloseConnection ()
{
    if (s)
    std::cout<<"entrou aqui ";
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Tua máquina é IPv6 ou IPv4?

Comment: ela é relativamente nova, tem IPv6 já

Comment: você não deve esta tendo "erro 4" porque esse código nem compila...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao testar o seu código, o compilador dá o seguinte erro:

```
program.cpp:23:16: warning: character constant too long for its type
 char meuHost = '127.0.0.1';
```

> Tudo indica que você está tentando passar uma string usando um char.

Mude essa linha para:

```
const char *meuHost = "127.0.0.1";
```

E essa:

```
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (&meuHost);
```

Para:

```
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(meuHost);
```